# JavaFX formatting DoubleProperty

Tags: binding, javafx, formatting

I have a binding for a rectangle on an canvas like this:

xLeft.textProperty().bind(fieldCanvas.layoutXProperty().asString());

The value returned in the TextField is returned with one decimal place. Since I'm working with pixels, I'm trying to get rid of the DP i.e. display as an integer.

How can I format the DoubleProperty (layoutXProperty) to zero DP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xLeft.textProperty().bind(fieldCanvas.layoutXProperty().asString("%.0f"));
```

Comment: Wow, what a quick reply. I tried many options, but the clue was the f in the format string! Thanks

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it answers your question